# Exclamation Dradis and DPKG error during apt dist-upgrade

Tags: kali-linux, dpkg

I am using kali rolling latest version. After performing **sudo apt update**, I tried to upgrade by doing **sudo apt dist-upgrade** but it shows following **dradis** error. Any ways to solve it? I also followed all the answers given in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795232/dpkg-error-processing-package-dradis) but didn't solved. Removing **dradis** would remove **kali-linux-full**, so I didn't try it.

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up dradis (3.6.0-0kali1) ...
Warning: The home dir /var/lib/dradis you specified already exists.
The system user `dradis' already exists. Exiting.
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from require at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:91)
DEPRECATION WARNING: before_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use before_action instead. (called from require at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:91)
Faraday::Builder is now Faraday::RackBuilder.
== 1 CreateNodes: migrating ================================================== =
-- create_table(:nodes, {})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "nodes" already exists: CREATE TABLE "nodes" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "type_id" integer, "label" varchar, "parent_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime)
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table "nodes" already exists: CREATE TABLE "nodes" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "type_id" integer, "label" varchar, "parent_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime)
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
SQLite3::SQLException: table "nodes" already exists
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
dpkg: error processing package dradis (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kali-linux-full:
kali-linux-full depends on dradis; however:
Package dradis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kali-linux-full (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I had the same issue... here's how I fixed it:

First, I figured I'd completely remove dradis (and kali-linux-full), the offending package(s):

```
apt-get purge dradis
```

That doesn't remove the `/etc/dradis/` directory, so I backed it up (wasn't necessary, but better safe that sorry) and obliterated the lil' bastard:

```
mkdir backup-etc-dradis && rsync -avrX /etc/dradis backup-etc-dradis && rm --recursive  /etc/dradis/
```

There's still some residual traces of dradis stuck in the couch cushions and what not (e.g. 'dradis' user), but luckily our package manager has a pretty high 'aptitude' to 'get' these sorts of issues and deal with them... ;)

```
apt-get install kali-linux-full
```

#### Voilà. Ready to roll. Hope this works for ya!